# Calling a class in one APK from another class not in the apk

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an apk that contains a classes.dex. If I baksmali it, I see a class inside it that I want to call from another class. This other class is not one that's in the apk, but is one that belongs to framework-res.apk.

Will I need to modify framework-res.apk's manifest, any other tips?